# Vertical align on image and text?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, styling

I have an anchor tag setup like below

```
<a href='' title='' class='video-author-box hoverbox'>
    <img style='height:32px;' src='IMAGE_URL' alt='' /> 
    Username
</a>
```

The trouble is that the text aligns to top of image, but I want the text to align in middle of the anchor and image.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qZFFX/2/

Comment: Needs some tweaking, but you can [`vertical-align: bottom;`](http://jsfiddle.net/qZFFX/2/).

Comment: More information on [`vertical-align`](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two simple solutions for that:

1. Remove `float: left` of the image, so it will become inline, and add `vertical-align: middle`

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/qZFFX/6/)

1. If you know the height of your image (32px in your case), set the `line-height` of it's container to it.

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/qZFFX/11/)

Comment: I'd upvote you, but I'm out of votes. Don't know why, but I was thinking it was `bottom` the OP wanted. `:s`

Comment: Thanks, Sinistra for the answer. Clean and simple.

Comment: Can you explain why using `vertical-align` on the image affects the text? an't understand this

Comment: It affects the image, centers it vertically to the line, but it doesn't have space to go up, so the text is pulled down. This only works for inline elements. You can't align vertically any block displayed element (e.g.: div). That's why you need to either remove the float: left, or use the second solution.

Comment: @SeanHJenkins - That might be a good question to ask, if it hasn't been already (cursory look, I didn't see anything).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

Add a `span` around the username and style like so

```
.video-author-box span{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:8px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qZFFX/3/

Then you can adjust the `padding` as you see fit.

Alternately, you could do this, without the use of `span`

```
.video-author-box{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:8px;
}

.video-author-box img{
    margin-top:-6px;
}
```

Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/qZFFX/5/

Comment: That's a bit of a hack, don't you think?

Comment: True @JaredFarrish.  But hacks are allowed ;-)

Comment: In theory, [`vertical-align: bottom`](http://jsfiddle.net/qZFFX/2/) should work, right?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, I made an second example without the `span`.  See above. `vertical-align:middle` works when the element is set to `display:table-cell`

Comment: Something tells me the OP would want this kind of answer only if all others were exhausted (no offense).

Comment: Probably right @JaredFarrish. I would use the other answer from SinistraD. Upvoted his answer.